Android Loopback Server: Restrict API calls to only apps installed in the managed work profile
I have an app installed on a managed work profile with a loopback server, that starts a localhost webserver.
I want the 3rd party app to make request calls with my local server.
I have no access to the 3rd party apps.
how i can differ the request API call between calls coming from Personal profile and calls coming from work managed profile.
for example: I have chrome installed on work and personal profile.
and my localhost have this endpoint: GET http://localhost:8080/user
i want to return success for API request coming from chrome installed on the managed profile and return Failed for the API request the chrome installed on personal profile
I've explored various avenues to identify if a request originates from a managed work profile, including inspecting headers and request properties. I even granted network logging permissions to my app delegate, but the logs weren't detailed enough and had significant delays.
I suspect there's a straightforward solution that I'm overlooking. I'm hoping someone in the community has encountered a similar challenge and can offer guidance

This is the entirely wrong approach for Android.  Android is not a OS designed to run servers.  It does not reliably run background processes by design, any non-foreground process is killed after about 2 minutes. There are a thing called Services which can be started when an API request comes in, but you would never run a local HTTP server on an Android device-  it won't be around by the time you need it.
IN addition-  you really wouldn't expect the kind of security you're asking for over HTTP.  Even on the web, there's no way to assure that a call to endpoint X comes from your code and not a 3rd party.  The most you can do is authenticate the user and assure the user is allowed to make the request.  You can't know it came from your code.  Sure, you could use a secret key param to the request, but that will be sniffed out within minutes by a competent hacker.  What you're wanting isn't cryptographically possible.

the embedded server is surely running in a service, thats not the question here.

@AnthonyKoueik I was editing a seond part in.  But it is also a VERY big problem with the idea.  Even a Service is killed after two minutes in the background, making running a local HTTP server on Android a failed idea.  You could run it as a foreground service which would give you more slack, but it can still be killed at any time by the OS without wanrning or reason.

@AnthonyKoueik Basically with a background process in Android, you have about 2 minutes before it's gone.  That pretty much kills the idea of anything based on an HTTP server locally, the OS does not provide support for reliabily running permanent background processes

i just need my service to run for couple of seconds. and then close

And how are you going to start it?  You can't have it waiting in the background for an incoming request.  That's why this is the wrong approach for Android.  A Service might be a usable approach, but a Service is not a webserver, doesn't do HTTP, and is started via Android intent

thats another issue doesn't matter now : ) I just want the answer to my question

It very much does matter.  But the answer is-  you can't.  It's cryptographically impossible.  You can authenticate a user, but you cannot determine that a request comes from an "authorized" app vs any other random app.  If you want to stop other ANdrodi apps from being able to send it a request at an OS level-  that functionality doesn't exist, and is HIGHLY unlikely to be added, as Android is not meant to run any servers.

I thought maybe there is a policy we can use from the EMM part
